# Which types of errors are there in a human language?

Tags: terminology, errors

A *typo* is a term used to refer to a situation when one (accidentally) mistypes a word or expression leading to a word or expression which is not the "expected" one, which may also be respectively an inexistent word or expression. I think we can also use the expression "spelling error". Can this also be called a typographical error? If not, what is a typographical error?

There are other types of errors. For example, when a person accidentally writes twice a word. How would you call such an error?

In general, *which words or expressions are there to refer to different types of errors?* I would appreciate an example of each type of error.

Is "grammatical error" a general term to refer to any type of error that may exist while using a (human) language? If not, then what other types of errors exist?

I am looking for an which may serve as a reference for other people. Note that I am just talking about human languages and, in particular, I am interested in the English terminology, context and language.

Comment: I observe that your examples are all about written language. Writing is a very special and divergent use of language, which requires the use of a wholly learned technology. Typos, and other errors of spelling and punctuation, simply cannot occur in ordinary language use, but only in writing.

Comment: @ColinFine Yes, I am also interested in errors which arise during the writing process. An answer to my question may put some emphasis on these differences.

Comment: Typographical errors refer to typesetting, like using wrong glyphs (Y instead of cyrillic У, hyphen instead of em dash), wrong layout, maybe including wrong binding and colour splitting. So it is more about the technology rather than the language.

Comment: @J-mster: that is the narrow typographer's meaning. "Typo" has entered general parlance as any kind of accidental error in typing or printing, most often a misspelling.

Comment: @ColinFine good point, but I did not mean «typo», only «typographical error». For me these are not synonymous any more than «car» vs «carriage»

Answer (score 2):

In *Aspects of the theory of syntax*, Chomsky distinguished "grammatical error" from language "performance error". In [Slips of the tongue](https://web.stanford.edu/~zwicky/slips-of-the-tongue.pdf), Fromkin distinguished spoonerisms, which conform to a language's phonotactics, from other speech errors.